# What type signature do generators have in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

Given that the new Python 3.5 allows type hinting with type signatures I want to use the new feature, but I don't know how to fully annotate a function with the following structure:

```
def yieldMoreIfA(text:str):
    if text == "A":
        yield text
        yield text
        return
    else:
        yield text
        return
```

What's the correct signature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [`Generator[yield_type, send_type, return_type]` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator):

```
from typing import Generator

def yieldMoreIfA(text: str) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    if text == "A":
        yield text
        yield text
        return
    else:
        yield text
        return
```

Comment: What is send_type, and return_type?

Comment: @Drew: you can send values to a generator using `generator.send()`. `send_type` specifies the type of these values. In Python 3.3 and up, when a generator uses `return some_expression` the returned value is wrapped in a `StopIteration` exception, and becomes the return value of a `yield from` expression (when [delegating to a subgenerator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator), see [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)); the `return_type` parameter specifies what type this'll produce.